# code generated calendar events is deleted when sync

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying using new calendar provider that only came with API 14 and above, I'm following this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html
it works like charm, but when i sync the calendar or when the calendar automatic sync it's self my events are gone or deleted, is anyone know what went wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: is it because the events not marked as new events? so when the calendar sync those events are deleted from device? if it so, is anyone knew how to marked those events as new events?